# Can i display in a canvas a youtube embebed video?

Tags: javascript, video, canvas, youtube

I try to reproduce a video in a canvas, and with the functions

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Works fine, but when I try with a youtube video not works (the video are inside of the iframe, off course)

My idea is take fragments of some videos and display in a canvas.

How can i do this with youtube videos? Any Idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplication of this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259626/render-youtube-videos-on-canvas-element

Comment: The question 14259626 not have answer yet, maybe someone answer this... sorry